# Using Leaflet or any js library with Typescript and webpack

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, leaflet, bundling-and-minification

***Note:*** I have searched a lot but I couldn't find my answer.

I am trying to create a map library by extending `leaflet`. But I think my problem is with using `js` libraries in general. I am using `webpack` and `ts-loader` to create the output file.

I have installed the types `@types/geojson` and `@types/leaflet` and moved them to *modules* folder.

here is my simple Test1.ts file :

```
import * as L from './modules/@types/leaflet/index';
import { MyDataItem } from './MyDataItem ';

export class Test1 {
    text: string;
    data: MyDataItem ;
    latLng: L.LatLng;
   
    constructor(theName: string) {
        this.data = { name: theName} as MyDataItem ;
    }
    public show() {
        console.log(this.data.name);
    }

    public showLatLng() {
        this.latLng = new L.LatLng(22, 55);
        console.log(this.latLng);
    }
}

module.exports = {
    Test1: Test1
}
```

I set `library:'lib'` in my webpack output option.
now I call the following methods from my browser console:

```
> (new lib.Test1("aa")).show()        // result: aa
> (new lib.Test1("aa")).showLatLng()   // error : L.LatLng is not a constructor
// or if it set webpack optimization:minimize to true  the error is: i.LatLng is not a constructor
```

I have added `leaflet.js` to the page so `typeof(L.latlng)` is `"function"` (`latlng` with small letters).

**Question:** obviously the types that I used from leaflet are not accessible after generating js files. My assumption was if you create ts declaration file (**.d.ts**) for any **js** library you can use that library in your ts files. what am I missing here? How to add and use normal js libraries in `Typescript` file so that they work after bundling them with `webpack`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual practice is to install both `leaflet` and its associated `@types/leaflet` packages in your `node_modules` folder, and to just `import * as L from "leaflet"` (or just `import L from "leaflet"`, depending on your webpack configuration). The types will be automatically visible. And webpack will automatically bundle Leaflet.

Same for all other JS libraries.

By importing *just* the types (`import * as L from './modules/@types/leaflet/index';`), you do tell TypeScript what `L` means, but not webpack.

If for some reason you *really* want to add the Leaflet library by yourself, instead of letting webpack bundling it with the rest of your application, then you have to tell webpack to leave `L` as it is, because you will provide it in global scope somehow. Configure webpack with [externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/#object), e.g.:

```js
module.exports = {
  //...
  externals : {
    "./modules/@types/leaflet/index": {
      root: 'L' // indicates global variable
    }
  }
};
```